# Web job triggered from azure logic app gets idle

Tags: c#, azure, console, azure-webjobs, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to Download large and many number of files from blob using a bulkdownload application.It is a triggered web job which runs for every 3  minutes.

Sometimes while running it gets idle.Throws the below error.

```
    [02/12/2020 09:20:34 > af14c2: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[02/12/2020 09:20:34 > af14c2: SYS INFO] Run script 'BulkDownload.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[02/12/2020 09:20:34 > af14c2: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[02/12/2020 09:20:34 > af14c2: INFO] Bulk Download Process Started....
[02/12/2020 09:20:35 > af14c2: INFO] Getting BatchID From Header with Status  Pending and Failed
[02/12/2020 09:20:35 > af14c2: INFO] URL  https://testapp.com
[02/12/2020 09:20:35 > af14c2: INFO] Batch ID is  4
[02/12/2020 09:20:35 > af14c2: INFO] Batch Running is  1
[02/12/2020 09:20:35 > af14c2: INFO] Document Count in DetailQueue for this Batch is 35
[02/12/2020 09:20:35 > af14c2: INFO] 1
[02/12/2020 09:20:36 > af14c2: INFO] 2
[02/12/2020 09:20:37 > af14c2: INFO] 3
[02/12/2020 09:20:37 > af14c2: INFO] 4
[02/12/2020 09:24:38 > af14c2: ERR ] Command 'cmd /c ""BulkD ...' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 120 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT 
app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed.
cmd /c ""BulkDownload.exe""
[02/12/2020 09:24:39 > af14c2: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[02/12/2020 09:24:39 > af14c2: SYS ERR ] System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.CommandLineException: Command 'cmd /c ""BulkD ...' 
was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 120 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed.
cmd /c ""BulkDownload.exe""
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.IdleManager.WaitForExit(IProcess process) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\IdleManager.cs:line 45
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.ProcessExtensions.<Start>d__13.MoveNext() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\ProcessExtensions.cs:line 254
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.<ExecuteAsync>d__31.MoveNext() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\Executable.cs:line 255
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteInternal(ITracer tracer, Func`2 onWriteOutput, Func`2 onWriteError, Encoding encoding, String arguments, Object[] args) in
 C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\Executable.cs:line 216
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteReturnExitCode(ITracer tracer, Action`1 onWriteOutput, Action`1 onWriteError, String arguments, Object[] args) 
in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\Executable.cs:line 165
   at Kudu.Core.Jobs.BaseJobRunner.RunJobInstance(JobBase job, IJobLogger logger, String runId, String trigger, ITracer tracer, Int32 port) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Jobs\BaseJobRunner.cs:line 272
---> (Inner Exception #0) ExitCode: -1, Output: Command 'cmd /c ""BulkD ...' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 120 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed., Error: Command 'cmd /c ""BulkD ...' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 120 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed., Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.CommandLineException: Command 'cmd /c ""BulkD ...' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 120 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed.
cmd /c ""BulkDownload.exe""
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.IdleManager.WaitForExit(IProcess process) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\IdleManager.cs:line 45
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.ProcessExtensions.<Start>d__13.MoveNext() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\ProcessExtensions.cs:line 254
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.<ExecuteAsync>d__31.MoveNext() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Infrastructure\Executable.cs:line 255<---
```

How to solve this?

Comment: It already tell to increase `WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT` value. Check this.https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#configuration-settings

Comment: Thankl you.I will try it @GeorgeChen

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: I specified in my appconfig WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT=180 and  SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT=180 but still the issue exists

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this idle situation, firstly you need to enable the `always on`.

And you encounter this situation, It's because the long-running job might be running in the background, butt SCM does not know it. So you could set `WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT`(mostly this is enough) and/or `SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT`(simply set both of them) on a high value under the configure in your app service. This is the time in seconds until Kudu will kill a WebJob that hasn't had any requests or output in the given time period. You could refer to this [doc](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#configuration-settings).